# Searching a list of 3 lists for equivalence of 2 lists and averaging all the values in the 3rd list where list 1 and 2 are equal (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of data samples of the signal strength at a distance and angle about a point. a sample of the data looks like this:

```
0.5,0,-21
0.5,0,-23
1.0,0,-29
1.0,0,-30
0.5,45,-22
0.5,45,-23
```

Where the data is organised radius, angle, rssi(signal strength).

As you can see I have multiple measurements for the signal strength however some have common radii and others have common angles. I am trying to find a simple way to move through the list finding all the rows with common radii and angle, average the rssi and append the radius, angle and averaged rssi to a new list.

The way I am trying to do it is:

```
import numpy as np
import math

#create 3 lists
original_data=[] # list to import the original data to
interim_data=[] # list to group rows with common radii and angles
R=[] 
P=[]
Z=[]

#import data
original_data=np.genfromtxt('bot1.csv', delimiter=',')

#convert rssi to linear
for b in original_data: 
    b[2]=math.pow(10,b[2]/10)

for item in original_data:
    if item[0] and item[1] not in R and P: #check if the common r and theta have been searched for already
        for a in original_data:
            if a[0] == item[0] and a[1] == item[1]:
                interim_data.append(a)
    #Once all rows in orginal data have been checked, average the result in interim data and place in averaged lists R, P and Z         

        Z.append(10*math.log10(sum(interim_data[3])/len(interim_data)))
        R.append(item[0])
        P.append(item[1])
```

However when I run this code Z, R and P remain empty. I have tried a few variations with more for loops but I am wondering if there is possibly a simpler way to do what I am trying to do.

I'm also having the problem when converting to linear values = 10^(rssi dBm value/10) I can't seem to get the indexing to work.

```
b[2]=math.pow(10,b[2]/10)
```

affects all lists in b, not just b[2]. Anyone know why that is?

Comment: there is no need to import both numpy and math.

Comment: Sounds like a job for either `itertools.groupby` or `pandas`

Comment: if Z, R and P remains empty means that the code never gets there. Beside: try to avoid explicit loops if you can and a double loop over the same array doesn't make much sense to me. ps: I tried to reformat your code substituting tabs (that have problems with visualisation, as can have different lenght on different systems) with 4 spaces, and I might have messed up the indentation. Can you please check it and edit to correct?

Comment: Yeh seems to be fine. When you say there is no need to import math and numpy does numpy have all the same functions ie I could replace math.pow() with np.pow() or does numpy import math itself?

Comment: You can see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html) the numpy math functions. I think that they are all the ones that you can find in `math`. I think that numpy reimplements all of them to be used on arrays. Check the edit2 in my answer, I get rid of one of the loop, that is useless with numpy. Then, just for the record: `np.pow(a, b)` is the same as `a**b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get what you want with something like this.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

data = np.array([[0.5,0,-21],
        [0.5,0,-23],
        [1.0,0,-29],
        [1.0,0,-30],
        [0.5,45,-22],
        [0.5,45,-23]])
# convert signal strength
data[:,-1]= np.pow(10, data[:,-1]/10.)

# get the unique values of radius and angles
uradius = np.unique(data[:,0])
uangle = np.unique(data[:,1])

mean_data = []
for ur, ua in it.product(uradius, uangle):
    samepoints = (data[:,0]==ur) & (data[:,1]==ua)
    if samepoints.sum() > 1:  # check if there is more than one match
        mean_data.append([ur, ua, np.mean(data[samepoints,-1])])
    elif samepoints.sum() == 1:
        mean_data.append([ur, ua, data[samepoints,-1]])
```

**Edit**

output (without doing the `np.pow(..)`)

> mean_data = [[0.5, 0.0, -22.0], 
>     [0.5, 45.0, -22.5], 
>     [1.0, 0.0, -29.5]]

**Edit2**

Numpy math operations act on the whole array that you provide, so there is no need of the loop over the rssi.

If you like more, you can also do

```
# convert signal strength
data[:,-1]= 10**(data[:,-1]/10.)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not too pretty but

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

original_data=np.genfromtxt('bot1.csv', delimiter=',')

data = sorted(original_data.tolist(), key=lambda x: x[:2])

[(k, np.mean(list(v),axis=0)[2]) for k, v in groupby(data, lambda x: x[:2])]
```

which outputs

```
[([0.5, 0.0], -22.0), ([0.5, 45.0], -22.5), ([1.0, 0.0], -29.5)]
```

I'm not sure what you're going for with the logs and powers but this should hopefully get you started.